# Make Eclipse CDT properly ignores my GSL span header

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, std-span

I use the Guidelines Support Library's `gsl::span` (from Neil Macintosh's implementation) - with the header located at `/usr/local/src/gsl/include`.

I also use nVIDIA nSight 9.2, i.e. Eclipse CDT version 8.4.0.nvidia-something. I've added the include folder as a CDT user entry under Project Settings | Build | C/C++ General | Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. - but this doesn't effect the indexer, which ignores the file. Also, the syntax highligher doesn't like it because it doesn't have a `.hpp`/`.h`/`.hxx` prefix.

How can get the `span` header to be properly recognized?

Answer (score 1):

For the syntax highlighting issue, the following should fix it:

- Go to `Preferences | General | Content Types`
- Choose `Text -> C Source File -> C++ Source File -> C++ Header File` in "Content types"
- Add the header name(s) to `File associations`

As for the indexer processing the header file, that should just work after adding it to `Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc.`, I'm not sure why it doesn't. Sometimes, I have better luck using `Path and Symbols` instead.

Comment: Well, that's not very scalable, since I would need to add every non-suffixed header, but ok. As for Paths and Symbols - I can't add include paths there for some reason! It only has "source locations", "output locations" and "references", and "source locations" have to be within the project directory.

Comment: ahhh... I just noticed eclipse has a list of the system headers for C++ in the filetypes dialog. Sad. Anyway, +1 for that.

Comment: @einpoklum: Do you have a suggestion for a better way filetype detection could work for files with no extension? If we don't have a whitelist, what would prevent Eclipse from trying to index every file without an extension in the project directory (e.g. `makefile`, any script without an extension, ...) as a C++ file?